# Difference between + and np.add()

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.arange(10)

b = a + 1
c = np.add(a, 1)

print("a:", a)
print("b:", b)
print("c:", c)
```

Which prints:

```
a: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
b: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
c: [ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10]
```

I want to know what is the difference between `a + 1` and `np.add(a, 1)`?

Comment: I don't think there is any.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.add` is the NumPy addition ufunc. Addition operations on arrays will usually delegate to `numpy.add`, but operations that *don't* involve arrays will usually not involve `numpy.add`.

For example, if we have two ordinary ints:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.add(1, 2)
Out[2]: 3

In [3]: type(_)
Out[3]: numpy.int64

In [4]: 1 + 2
Out[4]: 3

In [5]: type(_)
Out[5]: int
```

`numpy.add` will coerce the inputs to NumPy types, perform NumPy addition logic, and produce a NumPy output, while `+` performs ordinary Python int addition and produces an ordinary int.

Aside from that, `numpy.add` has a lot of additional arguments to control and customize how the operation is performed. You can specify an `out` array to write the output into, or a `dtype` argument to control the output dtype, or many other arguments for advanced use cases.

Comment: Additionally, you get additional ufunc methods like `np.add.outer`, `np.add.reduce`, `np.add.reduceat`, `np.add.accumulate`